# How can I convert Angular component to React component?

Tags: reactjs, angularjs

I am getting rendered Anuglar form from backend system (in api response). My application is in React. I want to display that form and add events on input box (can be more than one, and if user changes the value it should be update in state), button and dropdown. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers. See also: [ask]

Comment: Also why did you tag angularjs if this question is related to reactjs?